# Spring Boot SpEL ConditionalOnExpression check multiple values for a specific property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have created @ConditionalOnExpression("'${property1}'!='local,log-debug'
and '${property1}'!='local'") 
Do we have any optimized spel for this

Comment: What kind of optimization are you looking for?

Comment: i am using same property twice ${spring.profiles.active} . Is any way i can use like ${spring.profiles.active} != (local or local,local-debg)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use this

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("!{'local', 'log-debug'}.contains('${property1}')")
```